# How to SELECT from column WHERE we have multiple conditions in from another TABLE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 TABLES:

1. **movies** which has *title* and *id* columns
2. **stars** which has *person_id* and *movie_id* columns
3. **people** which has *id* and *name* columns

I want to write a SQL query to list the titles of all movies in which both Johnny Depp and Helena Bonham Carter starred.

When I write my query I do not get the title which both Johnny Depp and Helena Bonham Carter starred

```
SELECT title
FROM movies
WHERE id IN (   SELECT movie_id
                FROM people
                JOIN stars
                ON stars.person_id = people.id
                WHERE name = "Helena Bonham Carter" 
                OR name = "Johnny Depp"
            )
GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: Your code will not run in SQL Server, unless you happen to have columns with names like `"Johnny Depp"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT title
FROM movies
WHERE id IN (   SELECT movie_id
                FROM people
                JOIN stars
                ON stars.person_id = people.id
                WHERE name in('Helena Bonham Carter' ,'Johnny Depp')
                group by movie_id
                having count(distinct name)=2
            )
GROUP BY title
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also formulate your question as *"show me the movie rows where a related row for 'Johnny Depp' and 'Helena Bonham Carter' exists"*. This can be translated to SQL almost literally.

```
SELECT title
FROM movies
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT 'x'
                FROM stars
                JOIN people ON people.id = stars.person_id
                WHERE stars.movie_id = movies.id
                  AND people.name = 'Helena Bonham Carter' )
  AND EXISTS (  SELECT 'x'
                FROM stars
                JOIN people ON people.id = stars.person_id
                WHERE stars.movie_id = movies.id
                  AND people.name = 'Johnny Depp' );
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Correct, bad habit of mine, answer updated (additional [source](https://sqlitybi.com/exists-select-1-vs-exists-select-top-1-does-it-matter/)).

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you are saying that you want to see titles where both actors are present (used AND), but query says "OR" - one or second one.. SO maybe just logical operand issue?
Query looks good, but haven`t tested :)